# Make bash script always return success

Tags: bash, scripting, exit-status

I have an OpenVPN server which triggers a bash script when a connection is established. This script uses `wget` to post information to another server.

Today I noticed that when this other server is not reachable, `wget` fails, which makes the bash script return a failure, and the connection from the client aborts due to an "authentication problem". The problem was that the logging server could not get reached, but this should not be a reason for the connection to get aborted.

What can I do so that the entire script, which is triggered by a `client-connect /home/user/openvpn/scripts/client-connected.sh` entry in the ovpn config file, always succeeds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to tell it to explicitly exit with `0` (success):

```
#!/bin/bash

rest of your script here

exit 0
```

This assumes that your script will always run through to the end, so that `exit 0` is always the last thing that happens.

Comment: What could cause the script not to run through to the end, except for an earlier `exit` call? Does the `exit 0` get reached regardless of `wget` failing? I've read something about `set +x`, how could I use this if it were useful?

Comment: @DanielF if you chain commands together with `&&`, and the last one is the `exit`, then the `exit` won't run if the previous failed. Alternatively, if you have used `set -e` (exit on error), it also won't run. Since you didn't show us your script at all, I had to guess. Assuming you don't have anything like that then yes, the `exit` will run even if the `wget` fails.  `set -x` shows you the exact commands run as parsed by the shell (see `help set`).

Comment: Thanks, the script looks like yours, with `rest of your script here` being the `wget` call.